# Hyperlink in email to open mobile safari

Tags: safari, ios

Everytime I got a "Cannot connect to website" error when I click a hyperlink in my email. But it will show the page correctly after I click "Refresh".

What is the possible reason? Thanks.

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question. Please read [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Please read the ios tag you included.